# How to execute the Parent & Child request in sequence

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angular-promise

How to add child request to promise array. I am in need to execute multiple ajax request synchronously.

On googling, I came to know how to use `$q` with it.

```
    function _SearchData() {
    var promises = [];
    var callbackFunc = function(data) {
        dataService.get("https://childrequest").then(function(data) {
            console.log('inner ' + i);
        });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        promises.push(dataService.get("https://parentrequest").then(callbackFunc));
    }
    $q.all(promises).then(function(done) {
    })
};
```

This is making sure that `https://parentrequest` are executed in the sequence but still the `https://childrequest` are not executed in sequence.

This renders the output as

```
Parent #0
Parent #1
Parent #2
Parent #3
Parent #4

Child #0
Child #1
Child #3
Child #2
Child #4
Child #5
```

But what I am looking to execute the requests is as

```
Parent #0
Child #0
Parent #1
Child #1
Parent #2
Child #2
Parent #3
Child #3
Parent #4
Child #4
Parent #5
Child #5
```

Going forward, I tried the below approach but still it doesn't seems to render

```
function _SearchData() {

var promises = [];

var callbackFunc = function(data) {
    utilService.test("https://parentrequeste").then(function(data) {
        if(data.entity == "Parent") //first check
        {
        console.log("outer  " + i);
         if(data.id > 0) // second check{
        utilService.get("https://childrequest").then(function(data) {
            console.log('inner ' + i);
         })
         }
         else 
         {
            utilService.create("https://childrequest").then(function(data) {
            console.log('inner ' + i);
          });
         }

         }});});}


for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    promises.push(callbackFunc);
}

$q.all(promises).then(function(done) {

});}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always return something in every promise callback function

Try this:

```
function _SearchData() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
        var p = dataService.get("https://parentrequest").then(function() {
            // A return here:
            return dataService.get("https://childrequest").then(function (data) {
                console.log('inner ' + i);
                return data;  // A return here
            });
        });
        promises.push(p);
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

// Update (adding some conditions):

```
function _SearchData() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {  
        var p = utilService.test("https://parentrequeste").then(function(data) {
            if(data.entity == "Parent") {
                console.log("outer  " + i);
                if(data.id > 0) {
                    return utilService.get("https://childrequest").then(function(data) {
                        console.log('inner ' + i);
                        return data;
                    })
                } else {
                    return utilService.create("https://childrequest").then(function(data) {
                        console.log('inner ' + i);
                        return data;
                    });
                }
            }
            return null;
        });
        promises.push(p);
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);   
}
```

Comment: in case if I have some condition where should I put Please check this link https://codepaste.net/kv781t

Comment: There is a return missing in the else { ...

return dataService.create("https://childrequest").then(function (data) {

Comment: I have added the checks in the post. Can you please check & update the ans accordingly

Comment: Thanks mate, I am checking. Meanwhile I upvoted your ans. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the desired pattern of output.

```
function callParent(i, n) {
    if (i > n) {
        return;
    }
    console.log("call" + i);
    parent().then(function() {
        callParent(++i, n);
    })
}

function child() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get("https://childrequest").then(function(res1) {
        console.log("Got child data");
        defer.resolve("Got child data");
    })
    return defer.promise;
}

function parent() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get("https://parentrequest").then(function(res1) {
        console.log("Got Parent data");
        child().then(function() {
            defer.resolve("Got Parent data");
        })
    })
    return defer.promise;
}
var n = 10;
callParent(1, n);
```

**Working Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/rmu6wuo8/1/